# Validator doesn't seem to be used when it's set using @InitBinder

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm setting @InitBinder to set the validator for a Spring MVC controller. However, it doesn't look like validator is actually fired at runtime.

The controller looks like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {

final private static String USER_COOKIE_NAME = "ADVPROT_CHAT_USER"; 
final private static String CURRENT_VIEW     = "login";
final private static String SUCCESS_VIEW     = "redirect:welcome.htm";

@Autowired
private UserManagerService userManagerService;

@Autowired
private LoginValidator loginValidator;

@InitBinder("login")
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(new LoginValidator());
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
protected String processSubmit(@Valid @ModelAttribute("login") Login login, BindingResult result, ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        return CURRENT_VIEW;
    } else {
        model.addAttribute("login", login);

        String loginResultMessage = "Login successful via LDAP";  
        User user = getUser(login.getUsername());
        model.addAttribute("userLoggedIn", user);
        model.addAttribute("loginResultMessage", loginResultMessage);

        request.getSession().setAttribute("userLoggedIn", login.getUserLoggingIn());
        if (login.getUserLoggingIn() != null) {
            response.addCookie(new Cookie(USER_COOKIE_NAME, login.getUserLoggingIn().getId()));
        }

        return SUCCESS_VIEW;
    }
}

private User getUser(String username) throws Exception {

    return userManagerService.getUserById(username);
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
protected String initForm(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    Login login = new Login();

    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    if (cookies != null && cookies.length > 0) {
        for (Cookie nextCookie: cookies ) {
            if (nextCookie.getName().equals(USER_COOKIE_NAME)) {
                login.setUsername(nextCookie.getValue());
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    model.addAttribute("login", login);
    return CURRENT_VIEW;
}
}
```

At runtime, it doesn't look like the validator is doing any of the checks.

If I use @InitBinder without specifying the model attribute

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(new LoginValidator());
}
```

It looks like the validator gets fired on other obejects and I get exceptions. So, my guess is that the way I specify the model for @InitBinder is somehow incorrect but I'm not certain.

Comment: Does your validator implements `org.springframework.validation.Validator` and implements the method `public void validate(Object target, Errors errors)` ?

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't create a new instance of the validator in the `InitBinder`. It has to look like:

```
@Autowired
private LoginValidator loginValidator;

@InitBinder
public void InitBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(loginValidator);
}
```

Since you are using validator, you have to use `@Validated` and not `@Valid`. I mean:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
protected String processSubmit(@Validated @ModelAttribute("login") Login login, BindingResult result, ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
```

If you need a working example take a look [here](https://github.com/pedrogonzalezgutierrez/simplespringproject/)